# Pattern of sending multiple objects to the View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am doing my first project in ASP.NET MVC and using the NerdDinner sample project in ScottGu's [book](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) as a guide.  In his project, all his strongly typed views neatly correspond to the objects he defined (e.g. Dinner).  That is not really reality of a business application.

For instance, in my app, a page (e.g. View) gets most of its information from the primary object that the strongly typed View was created from.  But it also has to display information from a dozen other objects.

So, what is the preferred pattern of passing all this information into the View?

- Do I pass the primary object via the Model and the rest of the info via ViewData?
- Do I create a master object for each View that encompasses all the data I might need for that page?
- Is there a better approach?

Comment: Try to avoid the "ViewData"! ViewModel ist strongly typed and better than data piles :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may define your strongly typed `View` with [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

Ex: Your `View` needs a `Student` list and a `Teacher` List, then you may define a data transfer object (wrapper):

```
public class FrontPageDTO
{
    public List<Student> StudentList { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> TeacherList { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass an instance of this DTO to your `View`.

Answer (score 4):

The "master object for each view" is called a [View Model](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx).  That is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to View Models you can use Action Filters to pass "reference data" from controllers to views. See [article](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/aspnet_actionfilter_referencedata.htm) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing ViewModels for your application. Here is an example of creating a simple ViewModel.

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/659_Implementing_ViewModel_in_ASP_NET_MVC_Application.aspx